# Bash: Find a file from the root directory that has the word net

Tags: linux, bash

According to the [site](https://linuxjourney.com/lesson/find-command), excercise is:
Find a file from the root directory that has the word net in it.

I did:

```
find /home/ -name net
```

And nothing happens.

And I did:

```
find / -name net
```

And I received 100s of files with name net or permission denied.

Did I fail the tak successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-name net` will only find files named *exactly* `net`.  You want `-name '*net*'`.

If the exercise is asking for the root directory, it is referring to `/`, not `/home/`.  But note that there are a bunch of files under root that you don't have permission to view, which is why you saw those permission denied errors.  You can suppress stderr to hide these errors with `2> /dev/null`.

Putting it all together:

```
find / -name '*net*' 2>/dev/null
```